# Select all rows, and the average price of all rows where customerid = x

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

**[invoice_lines]**

*id(int), customerid(int), price(int), productname(text)*

I want to query this table, and extract all rows. But I also want to extract the average price of all rows with customerid = customerid.

So lets say I have one row that has these values:

*id(1), customerid(134), price(125), productname(Internet)*

I want to extract that row, but I also want a column which contains the average price of all rows which has customerid 134.

Any pointers? :)

Comment: Some sample data end wanted result please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE   @id INT
SET       @id = 1

SELECT    id, 
          customerid, 
          price, 
          productname,
          (
              SELECT   AVG(price) 
              FROM     invoice_lines i 
              WHERE    i.customerid = o.customerid
          )AS avgprice
FROM invoice_lines o
WHERE o.id = @id
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7102/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, customerid, price, productname, 
    AVG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid) AS avg_price
from invoice_lines
```

Comment: I think you would need a help of a cte in order to use it that way properly. I have a demo in my answer, test it against that. If you filter on the id, then the result is wrong.

Comment: I think you should write `AVG(price * 1.00)`, otherwise results will be rounded to Integer